# Glob to exclude a certain file?

Tags: glob, google-closure-compiler

Trying to compile my project with a header and footer script that will be at the top and bottom of the output file respectively. Between them I want to include every other script in the project, including going recursively into subfolders.

I tried `"..\script\header.js" "..\script\**.js" "..\script\footer.js"` And the header is showing up at the top just fine but the footer ends up somewhere in the middle. Is there some way to exclude the footer file from the middle glob so that it only gets appended to the end?

---

Edit: Running the compiler from cmd in windows with the following command:

```
java -jar closure.jar --compilation_level "WHITESPACE_ONLY"
  --create_source_map "source-map" --output_manifest "manifest"
  --output_wrapper_file "output" --js_output_file="..\script.js"
  "..\script\header.js" "..\script\**.js" "..\script\footer.js"`
```

Comment: There isn't enough information here. What flags are you using for the compiler. Is the compiler processing the flags or some other tool?

Comment: Edited question with more info @ChadKillingsworth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The compiler does process exclusion globs natively. There are a few options to force the order:

- [Use dependency management](https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/wiki/Managing-Dependencies). By utilizing either CommonJS or ES6 modules or by using Closure-library's `goog.require` and `goog.provide` calls, the compiler can auto sort your input files for you.
- Split your files up such that you can construct a glob that does not include your `footer.js` file.
- Use a pre-build tool that understands negation globs to handle your source file set.

Comment: Thanks! Got it working by sticking the footer outside the main scripts folder so the second glob doesn't match it.